# Check if all first elements in tuple list satisfies condition

Tags: list, scala, tuples

I want to check if a list is a subset of another, based on the first element in its tuple.

```
subset(List(('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)), List(('a', 4), ('b', 5))           // True
subset(List(('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)), List(('a', 4), ('b', 5), ('f', 6)) // False
```

The size of the lists does not have to be the same. I've tried something like this, but with no luck

```
x.forall((char: Char, num: Int) => {y.contains((_,num))})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map in the input lists to retain only the first element, then use some set functionality to check equality:

```
def subset(a: List[(Char, Int)], b: List[(Char, Int)]): Boolean = {
  val a_ = a.map(_._1).toSet
  val b_ = b.map(_._1).toSet
  b_.subsetOf(a_)
}
```

---

Update: Simplified based on suggestion from Luis

Comment: Why not just `b_.subsetOf(a_)`?

Comment: Consider the characters `aab` and `abb`. Is one the subset of the other? I don't think so.

Comment: I forgot to mention the characters are unique, but otherwise you're right @jwvh